# AngularJS Why use $q.all() on one promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm familiarizing myself with a codebase, and I'm seeing this everywhere:

`$q.all([promise]).then(responseFunc);`

This does not make sense to me -- I've read the documentation, and I don't know why the following is not used instead, since it's already one promise...

`promise.then(responseFunc);`

Is there something I'm missing? What's the advantage of the former over the latter?

Comment: Is it possible the `responseFunc` is used elsewhere with an array of data? If so, then the advantage is code re-use.

Comment: Or conversely the promise array may be generated from another array of unknown length making it simpler to make all cases use `$q.all()`

Comment: @charlietfl I'd agree, but I was only questioning the case where only one promise is involved, hence the deliberate `$q.all([promise]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bit weird, but there is a difference: `responseFunc` will be called with an array of the result instead of the result itself.

This probably should better be written as either

```
promise.then(res => responseFunc([res]))
```

or

```
promise.then(Array.of).then(responseFunc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the only advantage I can think of (based on my comment above)

```
function responseFunc(arr) {
    arr.forEach(data => {
        // do stuff with data
    });
}

$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(responseFunc);
$q.all([promise]).then(responseFunc);
```